# Swift Debounce On Touch Script

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

This program in swift is not working, I do not understand why this debounce does not work. Can anyone see my problem?

```
var numba = 0
var debounce = false
@IBAction func ChangeTouchUp(_ sender: Any) {
    if debounce == false {
        debounce = true
        numba = numba + 1
        Fire.text = String(numba)
        sleep(1)
        debounce = false
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking, but calling `sleep()` on the main thread is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE `Sep.28, 2017`:**

Sorry I didn't take a deep look at this post after submitting my first answer. It has been a while, but I'll try to add in some more details into this problem as it seems no one else actually tries to explain but just hits negative vote.

I believe the main reason for not getting enough answers is that *it's not intuitively understandable* what you are trying to achieve. Not all can instantly understand your point simply by using the word `debounce`.

The solution is not to use `sleep` on the `main thread`, as others already have stated, since the code is to be executed in the mobile system.

`sleep()` will block process for the current thread and this will result in blocking EVERYTHING including UI. Thus, this code will not only delay codes for `debounce` but will also block the button itself.

So I believe the correct way to achieve your goal is to use the code something like the followings:

```
@objc func targetFunc() {
    if debounce == false {
        debounce = true
        print("HIT \(count)")

        let deadline = DispatchTime.now() + 2 // 2 seconds later
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadline) {
            self.debounce = false
            self.count += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Not really sure if there's a better way to do it, but I guess this will do the job.

For more information on the `DispatchQueue` part, I would suggest to look for `Grand Central Dispatch`.

However, if you are trying to implement `debounce` feature in the real project, I still would recommend using `RxSwift`.

---

I believe the simplest way to achieve `debounce`, or `throttle`, is to use `RxSwift`.

You can check out this library from here

> https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift

This will allow you to do something like the following:

```
button.rx.tap
      .debounce(2) // or throttle
      .subscribe(onNext: { _ in print("tap") })
      .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```